# Why my codes throw NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I get this exception from custom's logs:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "12px"
    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
```

Then I check the related codes, but I cannot understand why this exception occurs:

```
String fontSize = styles.getStyle("font-size");
if (fontSize.endsWith("px")) {
    fontSize = fontSize.substring(0, fontSize.length() -2);
}
setWeight(Integer.parseInt(fontSize));
```

Thanks!

This is my fix:

```
try {
    setWeight(Integer.parseInt(fontSize));
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    setWeight(12);
}
```

Comment: Just run the debugger and see what happens

Comment: It appears that your substring method is not working properly, as the "number" has "px" at the end.

Comment: Your condition is false, so your String is not getting reinitialized. You are trying to parse a String that contains letters (px) into an integer. Check out the last line of the code.

Comment: maybe your `fontSize` String contains something else (like whitespaces). When I run your code with `fontSize="12px";` the condition triggeres, so I guess your String does not really end with "px" but maybe "px;" or "px " ?

Comment: If it contains whitespace, the exception should be: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "12px "

Comment: @xiahou you are right, we would see it in the exception. I didn't think of that.

Comment: It could be that the original string was "12pxpx", so just run the debugger as suggested and KNOW what's going on!

Comment: @Darsstar: It may be happened! No other explanation, I think. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
fontSize = fontSize.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
```

It will replace all *non-digit* characters with '' (nothing) and all thats left will be `12`.
You don't even have to test if your string ends with 'px', because Strings that don't have any non-digit character will not be touched.
All together it would give you this:

```
String fontSize = styles.getStyle("font-size");
fontSize = fontSize.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
setWeight(Integer.parseInt(fontSize));
```

Comment: I want to know why _fontSize.endsWith("px")_ does not remove the string **px**. I check the source file _Integer.java_, "12px" should be the original string.

Comment: @xiahou, sorry I don't have an answer for that – your code is correct and as I said, when I tried it everything worked without Exception.